# php bug the if is not work

Tags: php, operators, if-statement, file-get-contents

```
<?php   
$myip=file_get_contents("http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp");
if(!$myip=='1.1.1.1'){

    echo "Not matches";
}
?>
```

The if is not work? :S

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 5):

Do the if like this:

```
if($myip != '1.1.1.1')
{
    echo "Not matches";
}
```

**And [read this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php);**

Comment: @qwere, you know you can also accept the answer you like by clicking the 'tick' mark button on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your `if` to :

```
if($myip != '1.1.1.1')
```

or

```
if(!($myip == '1.1.1.1') )
```

`!` is having higher [**precedence**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `==`.

So your condition `!$myip=='1.1.1.1'` is treated as `(!$myip)=='1.1.1.1'` which treats `$myip` as boolean, negates it and then compares it with `true` (`'1.1.1.1'` is `true`).

Answer (score 2):

Question: What are you trying to do here? If you're trying to get the user's IP address, then no, this won't work, because the IP address that will be returned from the `get_file_contents` call will be the IP address of the *server*, not the user.

But you don't even need to make external calls to get the user's IP address. PHP already has it in the `$_SERVER` global variable.

```
print $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

This will give you the user's IP address.

Hope that helps.